# Is $2^e$ in the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(e)$?

Tags: field-theory, transcendental-numbers

As the title says, is $2^e$ in the field $\mathbb{Q}(e)$? I mostly study analysis, but this came up trying to answer someone else's question.

So far, my idea has been to suppose it's true and use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ is isomorphic to the rational functions on $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, we have $2^e$ being some rational polynomial evaluated at $e$. I got stuck trying to evaluate at new places. Clearly we can do it at $m e$ for some integer $m,$ but that doesn't help much. I'd love to take derivatives or evaluate growth somehow, as those are easy ways to show $2^x$ is not a polynomial.

I also tried to make use of the fact that $e$ isn't doing anything interesting here, other than being transcendental. Again, nothing.

I've looked into theorems about when numbers are transcendental, but most (all?) of the theorems prove things are transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$. This situation is different, and I don't see how to reduce it to the simpler case over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Yes, $e$ is euler's number.

Comment: It's $\mathbf Q(e)$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbf Q(X)$.

Comment: Right, that's what I mean everywhere. I'll fix it

Comment: Maybe try taking logarithms and reduce the problem to logarithms being transcendental/irrational over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You need to use something beyond just the fact that $e$ is transcendental; otherwise, for example, the smallest positive real solution to $2^x = 3x$ clearly has the property that $2^x$ lies in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$, despite being transcendental by the Gelfond-Schneider theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).